# c++ how to take ignore false data input?

Tags: c++

(Really bad title, please help amend it) I am writing a function that asks user to enter an integer, the function will return an warning if the input data is not an integer type. But it seems whenever the user input is 'char'/'string', the function takes in one character at a time, hence printing many lines of warning messages. Is there a way I could make the function take the false input as one piece of string? or just ignore the entire input?

The codes are as follow:

```
cout << "Please entre the number of data points (please enter an integer): \n";
cin >> dataNum;
while (cin.fail())
{
    cout << "Please enter an integer number. \n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> dataNum;
}
```

Similar problem occurred when I tried to take check data in a .dat file. I was extracting 'double' types from a .dat file but there was a line containing a string. Is there a way I could interpret the line as a whole? or simply skip the line? The codes are as follow:

```
ifstream myfile(fileName);
if (!myfile.good())
{
    cerr << "Error: the file '" + fileName + "' cannot be opened. \n";
    return(1);
}

// Dynamically allocate memory for data
double *mydata = new double[dataNum + 1];

// Read data from file, ignoring any additional bad data
while (!myfile.eof())
{
    if (myfile.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error: Rogue data detected. Bad data will be ignored. \n";
        myfile.clear();
        myfile.ignore();
        n--;
    }
    myfile >> mydata[n];
    n++;
}

// Close file
myfile.close();
```

Comment: `cin >> dataNum >> std::endl;` ?

Comment: The typical thing to do would be to grab an entire line with `std::getline`, and then validate it to see what you will pull out of it (or ignore it entirely)

Comment: The input data will never be of "an integer type". Input data is bytes, only. It is up to you to decode it into some form that means something to your program, in the context of the facilities provided by your programming language. Whether such a decoding is possible for some given data is what you're interested in, but that has very little to do with types. It's about whether the input data matches a recognised _representation_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

You need to guarantee valid input for the `double` type. The specific problem you're having is that you're not ignoring enough of the invalid input stream when you hit the error state. You need to reset the error state and then ignore everything in the current stream before trying again.

#### Example solution

```
double dataNum;
// we need to enforce that the input can be stored in double type
while(!(std::cin >> dataNum))
{
    std::cout << "Invalid value! Please enter a number." << std::endl;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

#### What it does

The `std::cin` stream has an error bit `std::cin.fail()` that gets set on invalid input (in our case anything that won't be converted to a `double` type. The error bit in `std::cin` is sticky, so when we hit an invalid input, we have to `std::cin.clear()` the error state, then `std::cin.ignore()` whatever data might be currently in the input stream. You need to ignore the maximum number of characters that the stream might be able to hold up to the line feed character, since there might be all kinds of invalid stuff in there. Then, we loop until our input stream received valid data that we can store into our `double` type. The `std::numeric_limits` resides in `#include <limits>`.

Answer (score 1):

You made a slight mistake.  You are calling

```
cin.ignore();
```

Which will only ignore a single character of the bad input.  To ignore all of the bad input you need

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```